# Data manipulation via regex in python for removal/editing of certain data in parentheses.

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, data-manipulation

I am having a little bit of an issue with my data manipulation below... **this is example code, normally each line in datas will always appear under the variable: "data"**

```
import re

datas = """Class (EN)
    Class (NA)
    CLASS (AA)
    CLASS-TWO (AA)
    Class3-A-H (NO)"""

datas = datas.split("\n")

for data in datas:
    data = data.strip()
    data = re.sub(r'\s*\(\w+\)\s*$', '', data)
    print data
```

If you run the above code the school classes are returned without the class code **(the bracketed part)**

However, I have a few variations which require different handling...

Example: `CLASS (NA) (N/A)` should be returned: `CLASS (N/A)`

Example#2: `CLASS (NA) (BB)` should be returned: `CLASS (B/B)` **(BB)** is the **only** one what should never get removed but instead changed to `(B/B)`

For example the following data:

```
CLASS (EN)
CLASS (NA) (BB)
CLASS (AA) (N/A)
CLASS (N/A)
CLASS (BB)
```

Should return:

```
CLASS
CLASS (B/B)
CLASS (N/A)
CLASS (N/A)
CLASS (B/B)
```

I think this is fairly complicated and I've tried a fair few things but I honestly struggle with the regex parts

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Comment: as I understand, you want get last letters in parenthasis? but then why CLASS (EN) should return just class :/

Comment: The current code removes ALL the data, including the parentheses from the strings but if a string contains `(BB)` needs to be kept NOT removed and then changed to (B/B). Same for (N/A) it needs to be kept, not removed. However in these two circumstances they could potentially have (EN) before them which needs to be removed...

Comment: Does this need to be done in a single regexp, or can it be a sequence of separate steps?

Comment: @abarnert either way, whatever's easiest I'm unsure how to achieve it.

Comment: @Hyflex: Two steps is easy. With a single step, it's definitely tricky. I think you could write an alternation pattern where the two parts match different groups isn't too hard, with the whitespace on each side also in capture groups, then a group that matches the empty string but resolves to `(?P=space1)\(B/B\)(?P=space2)` inside a `?(…)` group or something so you can `\g` it. Actually, if anyone can write that up, I'm kind of curious if there's a readable way to do it…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to do this is in two steps.

First, sub each `(BB)` to `(B/B)` (which you can even do with `str.replace` instead of `re.sub` if you want).

Then, since `(B/B)` no longer matches the pattern, your existing code already does the right thing.

So:

```
data = re.sub(r'\(BB\)', '(B/B)', data)
data = re.sub(r'\s*\(\w+\)\s*$', '', data)
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this one?

```
import re

datas = """Class (EN)(EL)
    Class (NA)
    CLASS (AA)
    CLASS-TWO (AA)
    Class3-A-H (NO)"""

datas = datas.split("\n")

for data in datas:
    data = data.strip()
    data = re.sub(r'^([^ ]+?) +.*\((.)/?(.)\) *$', r'\1 (\2/\3)', data)
    print data
```

outcome same as question gives:

```
Class (E/L)
Class (N/A)
CLASS (A/A)
CLASS-TWO (A/A)
Class3-A-H (N/O)
```

Comment: Did you try it? It doesn't give the desired output, or even close to it. The rule for whether to add the slash or delete is supposed to be whether it's `BB` or some other pair of letters, not whether it's last or not.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "works". Sure, it gives the output you show—but that isn't the output the OP wanted. If you can't understand his description of what the first sample input should give, try it on the second sample input, where he gives the intended output.